# JSF View State Auto Change and not able to handle it in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, viewstate

I am doing load testing but facing an issue related to ViewState, In our application View state along with csrf token shows in login, So by extracting using CSS Extractor I am to login and see the homepage, but once I navigate to any of page e.g TransactionHistory which hit using Post request i get an error of internal server inside request we are passing ViewState and page details but in response, it shows 500 internal server error I tried extracting ViewState but after extracting it did not work for me as ViewState keep changing, So need help regarding this how can we handle this.
[enter image description here][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL2jr.png
[enter image description here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLLjn.png
[enter image description here][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zbW4.png
[enter image description here][4]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Kv1.png

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to continue extracting the viewstate for each and every subsequent request, either copy the [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) to be a child of the `Manage Users` request or just move it one level higher - in this case it will be applied to all Samplers which are at the same level (or "lower")

You can see all pre-defined and generated JMeter Variables with all their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination.

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)